# Changed the port in Debian and forgot

Tags: ssh, debian, port

A dedicated server with Debian 7

Changed the port in Debian (/etc/ssh/sshd_config) and forgot.

How do can I find the port number?

Comment: Log in via the console, use the recovery console, nmap ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still have shell access the command:

sudo netstat -plunt

will list all open ports

You could of course also look at the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file, so I guess you no long er have local access.

If you no nonger have access you can use nmap (or zenmap if you would like a nice GUI) to map the IP, or ust run

nmap -sV xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the server's IP